# Find the Galois group of x5−1 ∈ Q[x], its subgroup diagram and the corresponding subfield diagram...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the Galois group of $(x^5)-1$ ∈ Q[x], its subgroup diagram and the corresponding subfield diagram of the splitting field of the polynomial $x^5 − 1$. Is it isomorphic to the Galois group of $x^5 − 2$∈ Q[x]?

I know that the zeros of $x^5-1$ are the 5th roots of unity and am having trouble where to go from there

Comment: How about factorising $x^5-1$ into irreducibles? Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry! this is my first stack exchange question! I know that (x^5 -1) factors into (x-1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1).  Im really lost

Answer (score 1):

The Galois group of $x^n-a$ is known:

**Proposition [Jacobson, Velez]:** One has $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ if and only if $n$ is odd, or $n$ is even *and* $\sqrt{a}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

Reference: [Computing the Galois group of polynomials $x^n-a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx)

For $n=5$ we obtain $G=\Bbb{Z}/5\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/4$, both for $a=1$ and $a=2$.

For the subfields, see for example here:

[Subfield of the Galois Group of $x^5 - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759230/subfield-of-the-galois-group-of-x5-1)

Comment: What would be the splitting field in this case?

Comment: The splitting field is $F=KL$ with $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{a})$, see the first reference above. For $a=1$ it is simply $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.